# Write a prolog program to find the sum of inverse of each number of n natural number

Tags: prolog

Write a Prolog program to find the sum of inverse of each number of n natural number

can't understand how to solve
I tried this method but didn't get accurate ans

```
sumofinverse(N,R) :-
    sumofinverse(N,0,R).

sumofinverse(0,R,R).
sumofinverse(N,T,R) :-
    N > 0 ,
    T1 is T+(1/N),
    N1 is N-1,
    sumofinverse(N1,T1,R).
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

method is correct

```
sumofinverse(N,R) :-
    sumofinverse(N,0,R).
sumofinverse(0,R,R).
sumofinverse(N,T,R) :-
    N > 0 ,
    T1 is T+(1/N),
    N1 is N-1,
    sumofinverse(N1,T1,R).
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**